# How to push data to an array-containing hash with `eval` in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to mirror the website which having the files and folder to hash.

[This one having example](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website-or-ftp/) So I tried, the following

```
my $url = "http://localhost/mainfolder/";
my ($parent) = $url=~m/\/(\w+)\/?$/;
my %tree=(mainfolder=>[]);


folder_create($url);

sub folder_create
{
    my $url = shift;

    my $cont = get($url);

    my ($child) = $url=~m/($parent.*)/;

    $child=~s/\/?(\w+)\/?/{$1}/g;

    while($cont=~m/(<tr.+?<\/tr>)/g)
    {
        my $line = $1;
        if($line=~m/\[DIR\].*?href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(.+?)<\/a>/)
        {
            my $sub =$1;
            $sub=~s/\///;
            print "$child\n\n";
            push ( eval'@{$tree $child}',$sub);
        }


    }

}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%tree,"\n\n\n";
```

Comment: Do you mean `push eval'@{$hash{$var}}', "somedata"`?

Comment: @Borodin No. `$var` having the braces means `$var = '{main}'`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval` anyway?

Comment: I think you need to go back another level and tell us what you're really doing. If you ask about using `eval` then people will give you answers showing you how to use `eval` - which is almost certainly the wrong approach. If you tell us what you're really trying to do, then we can help you come up with a better approach

Comment: @DaveCross Post edited.

Comment: An array strikes me as fundamentally the wrong data structure to use here. Nested hashes would make a lot more sense, in which case, you wouldn't be using `push` at all.

Comment: @EthanKaminski Not an array. It grows like hash of array of hashes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Instead of messing with `eval` you should use the [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) module

---

Because of the single quotes, you're trying to execute `@{$hash$var}` which isn't valid Perl.

If you wrote it as

```
push eval "\@{\$hash$var}", "somedata"
```

Then the `eval` would work, but it would evaluate to the contents of the array in hash element `main`, which is an empty list of values. That means your call would become

```
push( ( ), "somedata")
```

or just

```
push "somedata"
```

which is meaningless

This is a particularly unpleasant thing to want to do. Why do you think you need it?